# Custom form that will change the hyperlink inside the email for a chosen radiobutton

Tags: entities

I would like to alter the content of an email sent to the user after someone choice form radio button list. The altered content of the email would be a hyperlink to a particular version of a software. How do I do it within the submit button with Drupal 7 ? Thanks

Comment: Those radiobuttons may be part of the grid control.

Answer (score 0):

To send an email with Drupal, you should first use [`hook_mail`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7) to define the email and then `drupal_mail` to send it with any variables. There is extensive docs on this on the [Drupal API site](http://api.drupal.org).

Comment: Hi, I know how to send an email but I would like to know how to alter the content of the email to enable a different content of the email based on the selection the user makes.

Comment: @user6554 You pass the selection as a variable to `drupal_mail` and add the logic to handle the different cases in `hook_mail`. You can use any logic in `hook_mail` to determine the mail content.

Comment: Ok, this part sounds doable :) And how do I hooked up my code to the drupal document? I have to create a separete php file and somehow add a reference to the Send button or ?

Comment: @user6554 You create a custom module that has the code.

Comment: Ok, another term: custom module. So it's pretty simple I create one of those with my own logic and then probably move it to some add-ins plugins folder and it's available as a kind of form. I wonder if I can base it on a grid form for example and extends it's behaviour with my own ideas.